# How do I find services?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

What is the best way to find right service for dependency injection? Googling is not efficient yet. For example I spent quite long time figuring out that if I need current request passed to constructor by DI I have too use:

```
$container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()
```

Full code example:

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
        $configuration,
        $plugin_id,
        $plugin_definition,
        $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
        $container->get('logger.factory')->get('job_market'),
        $container->get('current_user'),
        $container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()
    );
}
```

And I've found above example in drupal class [Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Arequest/8.2.x)

Before that I've just found this 
[services list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/services)
but there is no description, no examples, nothing. Just a list with possibility to search.

How do you search for right service provider?

Answer (score 2):

A better way to accomplish this is to use the Drupal Console's  `container:debug` [command](https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/commands/container-debug.html). This command outputs a list of Drupal service ID's and its corresponding namespace & class.

```
$drupal container:debug  

 Service ID                 Class Name
 class_loader               Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader
 kernel                     Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel
 service_container          Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Container
 cache_context.ip           Drupal\Core\Cache\Context\IpCacheContext
 cache_context.headers      Drupal\Core\Cache\Context\HeadersCacheContext
 cache_context.cookies      Drupal\Core\Cache\Context\CookiesCacheContext
 ...
```

This command can be employed along with grep to search for a specific class name or service ID. For example: `drupal container:debug | ag 'DatabaseStorage'` to find a DatabaseStorage class.

Also of interest is the [PhpStorm / IntelliJ Drupal Symfony Bridge plugin](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-drupal-symfony2-bridge) if you use PHPStorm.

Comment: That's a good one but still it's missing description. So for example when you need current Request you have to use request_stack which is not so obvious. Description will definitely do the trick. For example: request_stack - allow you to get current request and do bunch of other stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drush and the devel module, you can also use 'drush devel:services'.

For example:

```
# drush dcs datab
- cache.backend.database
- database
- database.replica
- database.replica_kill_switch
- database_driver_uninstall_validator
- drupal.proxy_original_service.database_driver_uninstall_validator
- keyvalue.database
- keyvalue.expirable.database
- queue.database
```

It's not as cool as the console command because it doesn't give you the class name.

More ways to do it are also on this later question [Get the list of available services](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232008/get-the-list-of-available-services)