# Get the list of available services

Tags: 8, symfony-services

Is there a way to get the list of the available services in  Drupal 8?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

to Enhance  @4k4  answer, because it returns a lot of services names, if you looking for the specified service name, just pass a part of its name

**Drush only method**

```
drush eval "print_r(\Drupal::getContainer()->getServiceIds());"
```

for instances, if you looking for log services

```
drush eval "print_r(\Drupal::getContainer()->getServiceIds());" | grep "log"
```

and if you looking for  cache services

```
drush eval "print_r(\Drupal::getContainer()->getServiceIds());" | grep "cache"
```

**Drush with devel module**

Devel module offers a nice shortcut for drush

```
drush devel:services
```

or use its aliases:

```
drush devel-container-services
```

OR

```
drush dcs
```

OR

```
drush devel-services
```

**Drupal console**

```
drupal debug:container
```

So `drush dcs | grep "PART_OF_SERVICE_NAME"` will be a good sample to find a serice

**Update**

in new version you can just do it with `drush dcs PART_OF_SERVICE_NAME`

( thanks @Cameron to mention this in comment)

Comment: It takes a parameter so 'drush dcs PART_OF_SERVICE_NAME' works.

Comment: @Cameron thanks. I've update the answer with your comment.

Comment: Drupal console is IMHO not the best answer anymore. Drush can do it without any extra module, and Drush is maintained much better than Drupal console.

Answer (score 23):

The module [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) provides a searchable list (/devel/container/service).

For the command line use [Drupal Console](https://drupalconsole.com/):

```
drupal debug:container
```

Comment: That's perfect ! Thanks for help . Also found another solution we can search it at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/services

Comment: Yes, the list online is perfect for core services, but if you search with devel or console locally you'll also get services from installed modules.

Comment: I agree completely,actually I think looking with Devel is better because may be some contributed module provide some service which is not listed online.

Comment: It's too bad the devel list of services doesn't include the methods of those services. :(

Comment: @liquidcms, devel can't replace an IDE.

Comment: @4k4, usually very helpful.. but that's a bit of a silly comment. :(

Comment: @liquidcms, wasn't meant to be a silly comment. Devel is a runtime tool, providing a limited amount of data, collected when Drupal is bootstrapped. Programming with OOP methods on the other hand is what you do in an IDE.

Comment: Devel patch to add in list of service methods: https://www.drupal.org/project/devel/issues/3130469#comment-13577092

Comment: Or since Drupal Console does not seem to be active anymore, you can use drush to get this information. Make sure the devel module is installed and then run drush devel:services.

Answer (score 7):

With plain drush, no extra modules required:

`drush eval "print_r(\Drupal::getContainer()->getServiceIds());"`

If you are searching for a something specific, pipe the output into grep to filter the results, e.g. searching for "views"

`drush eval "print_r(\Drupal::getContainer()->getServiceIds());" | grep "views"`

Answer (score 4):

`\Drupal::getContainer()->getServiceIds()` is the REPL friendly way of doing this. Also you can use that on your module code etc..

The services can be also filtered:

```
preg_grep('/cache/', \Drupal::getContainer()->getServiceIds());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested to see the available services during development in PHPStorm you can enable the [SymfonyPlugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-plugin) which autocompletes for you the service names (and does much more other handy stuff)

It works both in **services.yml** and when calling **$container->get(...)**.

> [image]

Comment: Additionally in order for this to work properly you need to set your project as "Drupal project" on PHPStorm. Usually "he" is smart enough to suggest it to you when you create the project the first time. Check this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/drupal-support.html to find out more about Drupal's support on PHPStorm.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems one cannot stop the animation. It can get a bit annoying.

Comment: I will put it in spoiler.

Answer (score 2):

A list of services are available on drupal.org
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/services/8.9.x

Answer (score 0):

There is the [PHPStorm Metadata](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpstorm_metadata) module which can be used to get autocompletion for all services (core, contrib and custom) in PHPStorm. And it also can give you that list.

> This module allows to export PHPStorm Advanced Metadata in order to
> get autocomplete functionality and return type information for next
> calls:
>
> - `Drupal::service()`
> - `ContainerInterface::get()`
> - `EntityTypeManager::getStorage()`

After installing and enabling it, run `drush phpstorm-metadata:generate` and it will generate a file called .phpstorm.meta.php in your Drupal root directory. Inside there is a list of all available services (core, contrib and custom) mapped to their class.

> ```
> // ...
> 'theme_handler' =>  \Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeHandler::class,
> 'theme_installer' =>  \Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeInstaller::class,
> 'entity.manager' =>  \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager::class,
> 'entity.memory_cache' =>  \Drupal\Core\Cache\MemoryCache\MemoryCache::class,
> 'entity_type.manager' =>  \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager::class,
> 'entity_type.repository' =>  \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeRepository::class,
> 'entity_type.bundle.info' =>  \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeBundleInfo::class,
> 'entity.repository' =>  \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityRepository::class,
> // ...
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Since Drupal 8 used Symfony so you can run command `php vendor/bin/drupal debug:container` and this is equivalent in Symfony `php bin/console debug:container`

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. I would modify the post to add that drupal-console is required.